# Calling `doc-view-goto-page` in other buffer

Tags: buffers, window, frames, docview

I'm trying to control paging of a PDF file in `doc-view` mode. Say we have the following snippet

```
(let ((origin-frame (window-frame)))
  (with-selected-frame (make-frame-command)
    (let ((pdf-buffer (find-file "./test.pdf")))
      (set-window-buffer (get-buffer-window) pdf-buffer)
      (select-frame-set-input-focus origin-frame)
      (with-current-buffer pdf-buffer
        (doc-view-goto-page 5)))))
```

we make a new frame the display the pdf buffer then go back to our origin frame and try to scroll the pdf buffer to page `5` in the origin buffer.

`eval` the snippet, we can see the pdf buffer is actually displaying the content page `5`, while the mode line says `P1/12 DocView`.(Note that the first time you open the pdf it may take some time to convert the pdf and causes the snippet fail) Switch to the pdf buffer and press `n` which calls `doc-view-next-page`, we can see the buffer goes to page `2`.

That is to say, the buffer is **not** really went to page `5` just now but its 'content display' did. Using `doc-view-goto-page` in the pdf buffer will not have this problem as the modeling says `P5/12 DocView` after evaluation.

How to fix this? Is `with-current-buffer` not the way to go here? Thanks in advance!